# Augmenting an SQL query to translate an id for a human-readable value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m a total SQL newb, so please bear with me…

I have a data transform and load service sending nested JSON data hourly to a table in Google BigQuery. Based on research on Google’s site and this site, I have constructed the following query that is working well. This query ensures that the view has only the latest record based on the `_sdc_sequence field` and `_sdc_batched_at` field (since my data service is only sending in changed data each hour using Key-Based Incremental Replication):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
FROM 'the_database.the_salesforce_table.Lead' x INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT id, MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq, MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch 
       FROM 'the_database.the_salesforce_table.Lead'
       GROUP BY id
     ) xx
     ON x.id = xx.id AND x._sdc_sequence = xx.seq AND
        x._sdc_batched_at = xx.batch
```

I was hoping someone would be kind enough to help me amend this query in order to help me understand how I can aggregate and include data from another, sibling table.

In my Lead table there is a field, `convertedaccountid`. I wish to reference the `account` table, on which I can match against the `account` table’s `id` field to return the related `name` field – thereby converting the `convertedaccountid` value to its related human-readable value of the `name`.

**** EDIT ****
I misspoke a bit on the actual tables and fields, but the concept is very much the same.  Here is a crude table schema showing how I want to retrieve the 'name' from the Account table, by referencing against 'id' by way of the 'accountid' on the Opportunity table.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzvMh.png

(Sorry for my delay in updating this - recovering from surgery)

Comment: If you provide sample data and desired results, then it will be much easier to help.  There are simpler ways to get the most recent records from a table, if that is what you want (but that is not the question you asked here).

Comment: Can you provide your table's schema?

Comment: Updated with link to crude table schema and clarifying explanation

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've uploaded a screenshot of my schema.  Sorry for not providing it right off. If there is a more simple way to construct my view of the most recent (unique) items, I'm all ears.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you basically need to do a look up in another table you can insert another JOIN in your query just like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*, acc.name
FROM 'the_database.the_salesforce_table.Lead' x INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT id, MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq, MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch 
       FROM 'the_database.the_salesforce_table.Lead'
       GROUP BY id
     ) xx
     ON x.id = xx.id AND x._sdc_sequence = xx.seq AND
        x._sdc_batched_at = xx.batch
LEFT JOIN <account_table> acc ON acc.id = x.convertedaccountid
```

Please let me know if this helps you

Comment: My version of this query throws an error in BigQuery. Duplicate column name "name" since both my source and destination table has the same name I guess?

SELECT DISTINCT x.*, acc.name
FROM `analytics.salesforce_perpetual.Opportunity` x INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT id, MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq, MAX (_sdc_batched_at) AS batch 
    FROM `analytics.salesforce_perpetual.Opportunity` 
    GROUP BY id
  ) xx 
  ON x.id = xx.id AND x._sdc_sequence = xx.seq AND x._sdc_batched_at = xx.batch
LEFT JOIN `analytics.salesforce_perpetual.Account` acc ON acc.id = x.accountid LIMIT 10

Comment: @DJMonzyk it means that you have two columns named "name". In this case, try replacing `acc.name` with `acc.name account_name`

Comment: Awesome, @rmsteves, thanks, that worked great!  I lacked the SQL training to know that I could rename the output column. Thanks so much for your help on this, I'm on my way now!

Comment: Great! If it helped you in the end, consider accepting and upvoting :)